# See raw bytes being sent in COSMOS

Tags: ruby, cosmos

In COSMOS is there an easy way to see the raw bytes being sent over the line by the Command Sender? We want to capture what is sent out and don't know where all the protocol layers get added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Cmd Packets tab in the Command and Telemetry Server you can click View Raw on the command packet you're sending to see the raw bytes. Note that these are the raw bytes in the defined command. If your interface changes the data in some way (puts on a CRC, etc) then the bytes over the line may be different.

The following page describes the COSMOS log format: https://cosmosrb.com/docs/logging/

You can also add the [LOG_RAW](https://cosmosrb.com/docs/system/#log_raw) keyword after your interface definition to log all the raw data going out over the interface. Note that COSMOS does not interpret this log and you'll have to use a hex editor to view it.